# Why does Blender freeze when rendering with render layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

So as the title say, Blender freezes at the last point of rendering when I render with render layers. I'm quite sure that there is some problem with settings but I can't get what. In principle I could render layer by layer frame by frame, but that is such a hard work, that I don't want to make 600 frame animation in that way.

Here is couple pictures even though I don't think that they would help much..

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is just a copy of my real project so don't be surprised that there isn't any objects. I just get same results with this.

Here is the .blend-file:
[image]

Comment: So, you have freezing on Compositing part of render? Maybe there is not enough RAM. Also why don't you try to overlay this sequences in VSE

Comment: uh-oh.. sounds like someone found a limit to the power of the composer. We're still on Beta, so please report this layer-limit to the devs on https://devtalk.blender.org/c/blender

I know a combo-breaker when I see one. That means you´ve broken the tech barrier for the application. This is serious. Must be addressed. Please report this tech bug asap.

Comment: @SergeL Thanks for your comment! If I understood "Compositing part of render" correctly, no, I can compose my image, but I have to render every layer individually. About the RAM: according to Windows Task Manager I have it still much left when Blender freezes. And finally I'm kinda noobie with VSE etc. so I have to check that workflow out. Thank you again!

Comment: @PierreSchiller Okay. I know nothing about that forum, but I will research it and do my best to report this correctly. It could help if you had some tutorial, so I don't have to use time for searching that. Thanks for your comment!